# Transferring a file from another server in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have an executable hosted at code.google.com (say, http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe).   When the user browses to http://mysite.com/download.exe, I want them to automatically get the content of the file http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe without any redirect. The user should think that he/she is downloading the file from http://mysite.com/download.exe not http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe.

How might I do this, using PHP? Is there any special term for this process?

Comment: Can you elaborate this  Means user should think that he/she is downloading file at http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe not http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe

Comment: I get your point but what's the point? It really sounds malicious to me. What's your purpose? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You could use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to do that. Optionally you can cache the file locally and then send it with [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). Either way you have to send your [headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) manually.

Comment: I really think you shouldn't hide that information from your users.  I'd much rather download a file from google than I would from someone else's site.  Can you please explain this limitation?  Maybe we just don't have the full picture here...

Comment: The reason is my hosting doesn't allows uploading of file more than 2 MB. My site provides download for a software. So, I planned to host my '.exe' file at http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe such that when user open http://mysite.com/download.exe, he/she will get the file hosted on http://code.google.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use URL rewriting to pass in the file name as an argument to a script. Your script (downloadexecutable.php in this example) would respond to a $_GET argument 'q' which would contain 'download':

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q'] == "download") {
    //you will want to:
    //1) set Content-type to be the correct type...I just set it to octet-stream because I'm not sure what it should be
    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename('http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe').'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize('http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe'));    // provide file size
    echo file_get_contents('http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe');      // push it out
    exit()
}
?>
```

Then, you would enable URL rewriting on Apache in an .htaccess file in your root directory like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.exe$ /downloadexecutable.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

When the user requests any file ending in .exe, downloadexecutable.php should be executed as follows:

Request: http://yoursite.com/download.exe

What actually gets processed by PHP: http://yoursite.com/downloadexecutable.php?q=download

Request: http://yoursite.com/this/could/be/a/bug.exe

Processed: http://yoursite.com/downloadexecutable.php?q=this/could/be/a/bug

Obviously it would need a bit of work and I haven't tested any of the above, but if you fool around with it a bit and are willing to use google, you should be able to get it working.

URL Rewriting tutorial: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Source for the php stuff: http://snipplr.com/view/22546/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this approach:

```
<?
function get_file($url) {
$ficheiro = "file.exe";
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . "/$ficheiro", 'w+'); //make sure you've write permissions on this dir
//curl magic
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
}

//sets the original file url
$url = "http://code.google.com/fold/file1.exe";

//downloads original file to local dir
get_file($url);

//redirect user to the download file hosted on your site
header("Location: $ficheiro");
?>
```

and add this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download.exe  this_script.php
```